# Filebackup failed - In event log the "Virtual Disk Service" has stopped (at nearly same time)

Tags: backup, windows-service, backupexec, vds

We have an Windows 2008 R2 server which is used as file server.

At the weekend my colleague makes a file-backup via backup exec. We do this on many servers but only this one make problems. We have this issue for about four weeks.

Backup Exec starts at saturday night and fails every sunday at nearly the same time: 8:18.

The erorr meassage we recieve in Backup Exec is this one:
"e00084f8 - The network connection to the Backup Exec Remote Agent has been lost - Check for network errors" - see more information here about this error here:
http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH153800&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1412580918437

i didn't know what could be the problem, because our monitoring didn't show any network problems as mentioned in the error message. Both servers (file server and backup server) were reachable during the whole time. But then i checked the event-log on the fileserver and saw, that in 4 cases the "Virtual Disk Service" has stopped at nearly the same time as backup exec gets the error.

8:17 - Virtual Disk Service - Service was stopped - Event-ID 4.

So i think this is the problem. But what can i do? Is the virtual disk service needed, or can i just test to disable the service? Or has anybody else had a similar problem?

The Server is a HP ProLiant DL180G6.

By the way: After the error occurs backup exec starts again and is successful. But because there are so many files the backup needs time till early Tuesday!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem seems to disapear after upgrade the BEREMOTE Agent (Backup Exec) on the Server...

Answer (score 0):

Are you backing up to a Disk-based storage ? If yes, then the Virtual Disk service stopping can cause this type of a backup failure.

Additionally, check what time the Backup Exec daily maintenance is set to run. Do ensure it does not conflict with the backup job timings. If running an AV scan, set it to exclude from scanning the BE processes. Check Windows Scheduled Tasks as well.

Lastly, check if the Remote Agent service is stopping/crashing on either server. Usually, there would be an event id 1000 logged.

Hope this helps.

Vivek
Technical Support Engineer, Advance Team
Backup Exec & DLO Support, Symantec Corporation

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Yes, Backup is to Disk. We already checked for other tasks which are running at the same time but we didn't find some tasks... In event-Log i can also not see any event id 1000 for stopping/crashing Remote Agent service... Last failure from BeRemote i see is from January...